# VSX 2010 Package Updates via Network or reinstall Locally?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx

Here is the scenario.  I have a working VSX package Proof of Concept that has been accepted by the team.  The question of Updates came up today.  Can the package be updated Globally across the Network or does it have to be reinstalled Locally with each change in the package? If locally, do Admin Rights come into play?

As always Thanks

Danny

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This question was also cross-posted [on the Visual Studio Extensibility Forum on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/bdbb2aa4-ed63-435d-81e0-e38171aa215f). Repeating the answer here.)

I presume you're talking about the Updates tab in the Extension Manager dialog (and the bubble you may see if the Pro Power Tools extension is installed).

If this is an extension you've developed that will remain internal to your organization, users will not be informed of updates. In Visual Studio 2010, the Extension Manager will only query the Visual Studio Gallery for available updates.

Comment: If you are interested in an answer to this question using internal updates remotely check out the forum cross reference=Danny